# How to estimate an influence of electromagnetic devices on each other?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics

I have a few electomagnetic devices: one is a gps antenna, next is a receiver (950 Mhz), third is a radio transmitter that radiates with 2.41 GHz and the last is a height sensor that uses 24 Ghz signals for measurements. All they are placed quite close - about tens of centimeters from each other. They are going to be set on a drone. How can I reduce the possible technical troubles?

Comment: Test. Screen between devices internal to the drone. Spread antennas out. However, this type of setup is not unusual for drones or balloons launched by high school science classes.

Comment: What type of screen do you mean? One with a special metal film patterns which reduce the EM radiation with help of diffraction? I think a simple metal sheet will have no effect as is polarised

Comment: Just solid copper foil will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were designing for collocation you'd design filters to isolate somewhat the harmonics or spectral sidelobes in band to others, and if it was serious you'd test on some aircraft model. This sounds like a home project.

It sounds like you just bought the equipment, you have to live with whatever comes out. You could try filtering some between the antennas and the RF equipment. In spreading the antennas you might find some scalloping of the patterns and if you move them some it can improve. The 24 GHz is probably the safest, far enough from the others, but it depends on some possible offending LO harmonics or others leaking out. Gps and the 2.4 GHz transmitter coexist in all cell phones, though 2.4 in cells and wifi's are sharing freq by sometimes using their own times lot. Don't know if your 2.4 radio is a continuous signal, or time slotted, and the biggest concern is if it's high power. If just wifi powers you might be ok.

Unless you want to spend some time calculating possible harmonics etc power levels test with the radio transmitter separated from the other antennas first, move around the most likely offenders and sensitive receivers.

Comment: Comprehensive answer. Many features noticed. Thanks